# How do I add a wordpress.com blog to Bing?

Tags: seo, search-engines, wordpress, bing

I am running a Wordpress blog. It shows up for Google search with my name, but it’s not indexed at all by Bing. Can I add it somehow to Bing? I added it to Bing Webmaster tools, but it doesn't see a sitemap.

EDIT: I tried to submit the sitemap, but it silently fails.

EDIT 2: I succeeded with submitting the sitemap. It now shows as „Pending”.

Comment: Don't necessarily get your hopes up. In case you didn't click through, the problem mentioned in my response is that sitemap submissions stay "pending" forever.

Answer (score 3):

There's no obvious good solution here.

Your site being indexed by Google tells you nothing as far as the question. That has no bearing on whether it is, or even *should*, be indexed by some other engine.

There's some kind of [unspecified problem with submitting sitemaps to Bing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24725/how-long-does-bing-bot-typically-take-to-process-a-sitemap-submission/24833#24833). So, you're basically stuck waiting for their spider to happen across your site, which you'll note someone in that thread also claims has a tendency to be slow(anecdotal). The best thing you can do right now is see if you can get some links back to your site, increasing the chances it'll be followed by a crawler.